# Prevent javascript function to access DOM

Tags: javascript, multithreading

Does anyone know if its possible to prevent a JavaScript function from accessing the DOM?

More info:

I am trying to create a "Threading" object for JavaScript, e.g. use the Worker object, fall back on setTimeOut when not available. Obviously the worker can't access the DOM, I would like to keep this standard.

Even more info:

One possible, but ugly possible solution (that I figured out just now):

```
function test(document, window)
{

}
```

*But Nothing prevents the dev to access the dom from another function he calls within this function though - and you'll have to list the world of arguments.*

Comment: why? what are you trying to do?

Comment: A function only does what you define it to do. If you don't put in any DOM methods, I'd say you've prevented it!

Comment: I am trying to create a "Threading" object for JavaScript, e.g. use the Worker object, fall back on setTimeOut when not available.
Obviously the worker can't access the DOM, I would like to keep this standard.

Comment: Exactly, usually it is better to share the problem in stead of coming up with a solution. What you could try is to override all functions that modify the DOM.. But really a bad practise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not really possible in a normal browser environment.

You might be able to replace stuff like `document.getElementById` before calling the function and restoring it afterwards though... But I'm sure there are ways to get around this.

Comment: I guess No is so far the best answer? hehe

Answer (score 2):

You could execute the function in a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers). There is no access to DOM from a Web Worker.

But really, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I actually want to recreate this exact same thing e.g. create a threading object that makes use of the worker object and falls back on setTimeout - while keeping the non-dom access standard.

Comment: @Helix, are you loading third party javascript, or why such concern about DOM modification?

Comment: If a developer uses my object and writes his code in IE 9 and lower, he will be able to access the DOM, which doesn't help seeing that the code won't work in Chrome etc (since they'll use a worker) - so I'd like the behavior to be the same in IE

Answer (score 2):

Since your goal is to enforce conventions rather than to completely sandbox the JavaScript, you could indeed use a function with `window`, `document` and other DOM interfaces shadowed locally and then eval the third-party script:

```
(function test(window, self, top, document) {
    'use strict'; 
    eval(untrustedCode);
}());
```

Of course they still could access the real global object, but at least not directly.